# How can I inject HTML/CSS content using content scripts of my fixefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add-on and I need to inject large chunks of HTML/CSS into the DOM based on a function result in my content script. Here is my main.js script (you may want to skip this part).

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require('sdk/self');
var pull = self.data.url;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [ 
    pull('vendors/jQuery.js'), 
    pull('util.js'), 
    pull('views.js'), 
    pull('myScript.js')]
});
```

myScript.js needs to inject some html/css form data directory of my addon into DOM. how can I do this?
I tried to use jQuery load and get functions but it didn't work.
I wish I could do some thing like this:

myScript.js

```
var html = $.get(chrome.extension.getURL("html/place-holder.html"), function (data) )
   //I will append html to the DOM 
});
var css = $.get(chrome.extension.getURL("css/style.css"), function (data) )
   //I will append css to the DOM 
});
```

This is the way I did it in Google Chrome but it seems to be much harder in Firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### main.js

```
const {data} = require('sdk/self');
require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [ 
    data.url('vendors/jQuery.js'), 
    data.url('util.js'), 
    data.url('views.js'), 
    data.url('myScript.js')],
  contentStyleFile: data.url("css/style.css"),
  contentScriptOptions: {
    html: data.load("html/place-holder.html")
  }
});
```

### myScript.js

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', self.options.html);
```

Comment: No worries. I'm looking forward to learning how to build Chrome extensions. It's cool that you have access to a `chrome` object inside the content script. With the Add-on SDK, you can pass information to the content script via `contentScriptOptions` or by passing them with `port.emit`, but you don't get access to the modules from within the content script.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if you set `pull` correctly. try setting `var pull` to just `self.data` instead of `self.data.url`

Comment: pull is a shortcut function I made for my self and it's working. I just don't know how too inject HTML/CSS files into the DOM.